# AJAX return true/false if user logs in and change div color

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get a div change colors when the user logs in.

the php:

```
if($loggedin === "1"){                      
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

right now it skips the check and just shows a green div whether or not the user is logged in.

any help is much appreciated!

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                setInterval(function() {
                    $.getJSON("includes/widgets/check_status.php", function (res) {
                        if (res === true) { // logged in
                            $('.status').css('background', 'green');
                        } else { //logged out
                            $('.status').css('background', 'red');
                        }
                    });
                }, 3000);
            }); 

        });
```

Comment: You are not performing an AJAX request here. Also, do you really want to perform this call every 3 seconds?

Comment: how do I perform the ajax request? and ill change it to 10 seconds later

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX real time css background color update for logged in users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749331/ajax-real-time-css-background-color-update-for-logged-in-users)

Comment: No one is answering there and not gaining views even and I am really trying to solve this issue I have with the code

Comment: I am trying to help but putting all into answer takes some time..

Comment: no problem, i appreciate that. can't wait to see what you got for me!

Comment: @Kiyarash I looked at your code but it didn't work. All help is appreciated

Comment: any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is there any problem still???

Comment: yeah i can't get the divs to change color for all users that log in, i get only one at a time. Also when the user logs out, it won't change on a different browser unless i refresh which is not real time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- You are not performing an ajax request: The function inside `setInterval` does nothing at the moment. You need to call jQuery's `$.ajax` (or an alternative like $.getJSON)

You can modify your callback function inside `setInterval` as follows:

```
function() {
    $.getJSON("includes/widgets/check_status.php", function (res) {
        if (res === true) { // logged in
            $('.status').css('background', 'green');
        } else { //logged out
            $('.status').css('background', 'red');
        }
    });
}
```

- When returning from PHP, you should echo something.

Preferred data type for such communication is JSON:

```
if ($user_data['status'] === "1") {                       
    echo json_encode(true); // In fact json_encode(true) is "true", but being explicit might help in the future
} else {
    echo json_encode(false);
}
exit; // this is required to prevent anything below to be appended to response
```

I guess you know the difference between == and === in both [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) & [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript). Using === in javascript side here will not harm because we are returning boolean data from PHP, we are encoding it to JSON and transparently parsing JSON on javascript side ($.getJSON does parsing for us). On PHP side, if `$user_data['status']` is not a string (for example if it is integer 1) then comparison will fail. (`1 === "1"` is false). So you need to validate types there.

Comment: please take a loot at my EDIT 2, I tried this and nothing seem to change, still no color change whether i log in or not

Comment: that is not a proper use of Ajax. You cannot have setInterval call there. it should be outside ajax call

Comment: i fixed that. still no lack with the color change on log in or log out

Comment: sorry I cannot help further. The code I supplied is not supposed to run as is, it was meant to give you the idea. You should check documentation to fix anything missing

Comment: this didn't really help but i guess ill mark it as an answer

Comment: I think it is helpful. But if it didn't please **do not** mark it as answer

Comment: well it doesn't change the colors.. I need it to change the colors for the posts where the author logs in, not all the posts on the website

Answer (score 0):

You might have issues in your ajax response.

Try :

```
console.log(response);
```

In your `success` event. (You'll be able to see the output in the console - F12 on most browsers, console tab).

I'm not sure you can use `setInterval` like that.

Try :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function check_login(){
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://www.mysite.com/check.php',
      }, 
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          console.log(data);
      }
    });
    } 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval("check_login()", 3000);               
     });
     </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

When jQuery `Ajax` return `response text`-***`the first argument of success`***, the response contains `headers`, not pure string ***`true`***... 
So, if you want check if the `php` condition is `true` or `false`, I suggest you:

You didn't send Ajax request:
***try this***:

```
    $.ajax({

    type: "post",//or GET
    url:"url",
    beforesend: function() {
        //do stuff that you want to run before send
    },
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert("page not found...");
        }
    },
    success: function(response){                     
                            if(response.indexOf("true") > 0 ) { //logged in
                                $('.status').css('background', 'green');
                            }else { //logged out
                                $('.status').css('background', 'red');
                            }
                        }
```

which means your response text contain `php` condition as `true`...

Comment: still didn't work for me.. I don't get the background changing

Comment: would you explain why you are using `setInterval`?!?!?!

Comment: to check every x seconds for updates (if the user is still logged in or not)

Comment: and where is `$.ajax` or `$.get` or `$.post`?!?!? you just used $.ajaxSetup

Comment: as much as I know. `$.ajaxSetup` just change setting for `$.ajax`

Comment: there is nothing to post, get, as this is not a form as far as my knowledge of ajax goes. and not sure, can you tell me the correct way?

Comment: if you don't send data, in `jQuery` ajax method, get and post do the same... but you can use get in this `case`...

Comment: I tried your code and nothing changed. I still have no color change on log in and log out